# Nonlocalized icons are used on comments from deleted user page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, deleted-accounts, icons

Instead of localized "В" and "О" icons I see the English "Q" and "A" on comments from deleted user page:

> [image]

On the other pages localized icons are used:

> [image]